# how can i can extends from combobox in vaadin 23+?

Tags: java, vaadin

i need create new component, extends combobox with grid below it (not custom render,
a separate grid). when i get click event, i should reload table.

i want to get such a component so that it can be replaced with vaadin's, that's why i extends combobox out of the box.

the problem is i can't get layout from parent and can't add grid to "this".

if me implements hasCompoment interface, i can't add "this" on layout...

so my question: how can i add some components to combobox? or i should use Component as parent class and implements all methods from interfaces?

Comment: Why don't you create a composite component with a TextField and a Grid?

Comment: It might also help to add, what your ultimate goal here is: do you want to create a new _field_ (e.g. `HasValue`) or just some display of values where the combobox acts as a filter?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli because i need combobox compoment as combobox with some my custom extensions

Comment: @cfrick you right, i want new field (combobox with custom grid-view selected item), but i want to use all combobox features without rewriting all 2k lines :(